# Create text file with Windows-1250 encoding (google app script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to write txt file from Google Sheets to Google Drive, all is OK but when create file by DriveApp.createFile, it is saved with UTF8 encoding. I need Windows-1250. How can I do it? Can't find in docs.

Comment: After doing some testing and research, I am not sure it is possible to do this with google docs.

Comment: I am disappointed that I will have to do this conversion with external tools: ((

Comment: Is there any workaround of the problem?